# Use GETPIVOTDATA for grouped data

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable where the rows are values from a field called `ID`, which is a number, two columns: `Light` and `Humidity`, and a set of values `Temp`. I want to find the max value for `Temp` over a grouping of IDs. I grouped the IDs from number 1- 100, which encompasses all IDs in the PivotTable, leaving me a PivotTable with a single row of data. In each column I now have the maximum `Temp` value at a given `Light` and `Humidity` value. This is all looking good, until I try to use these max values.

I am trying to use a function like so:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Temp", Controls!$A$15, "Light", 50, "Humidity", 10)
```

As well as:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Temp", Controls!$A$15, "Light", 50, "Humidity", 10, "ID", "1-100")
```

But this gives a `#REF` error.

Prior to grouping the IDs into a single group, I could use a function like:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Temp", Controls!$A$15, "Light", 50, "Humidity", 10, "ID", 1)
```

And this would correctly return the "Temp" value for `ID` 1 where the column values match those given in the function.

How can I modify this query to successfully get the value by a grouping of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test it seems that the first number of the group can be used in the GetPivotTable formula, so if the group starts with `4`, this formula will return the correct result:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("temp",$H$3,"light",50,"humidity",10,"id",4)
```

As an alternative, you could add a helper column to your source data and use a formula that returns the group for each respective ID.

In the screenshot the upper pivot table uses the "Group" functionality and it is not possible to get a GetPivotData of that. The lower pivot table, however, uses the same grouping, which is achieved by the helper formula in column F.

```
="group "&CEILING([@id]/3,1)
```

This allows a single value to cover the group and that single value can be used in GetPivotData.

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("temp",$H$10,"light",50,"humidity",10,"group","group 2")
```

[image]